# A conceptual question regarding plane and sphere intersection and a given point outside both of them.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, spheres

How do we find the closest point on the surface of the sphere to the given point outside of the sphere?

Well, my answer would be to construct a line between the centre and the given point and find the closer intersection. You can also do it using a unit vector of the given point and multiplying it by the sphere's radius. This makes it both intuitive and easy to show algebraically.

The confusing part for me is finding a point on a circle (formed by the intersection of a plane and a sphere) that is closest to the given point.

For example, consider a circle with a centre and radius: $$C = (6, 3, 6); r = 12 $$ respectively and a point outside $$P = (33, 30, 6)$$

I am only familiar with circles when we have $x$ and $y$ variables. Visualising this didn't help my conceptual understanding as I couldn't seem to find a way to express it.

Does anyone have any advice or tips on how to go about this? Thank you! I am adding an image to show what I mean and where the circle I mentioned is formed.

E.g.

[image: A sphere with the plane intersection forming a circle and a given point outside]

Comment: You can use Lagrange multipliers for this. Are you familiar with those?

Comment: @GReyes Unfortunately, not yet, this is in the first Linear Algebra semester.

Comment: Here is another way: you can consider a plane containing your point and both the center of the sphere and the center of the circle. That plane will intersect the circle at two points: the closest and the farthest. Then you can just compare two numbers to choose.

Comment: @GReyes I had this idea too though how do I check where they intersect without the equation of the circle? Or rather I have the equation but it is in a 3D form, I am unsure how that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intersecting plane (the one that determines the circle) has equation
$$
\pi: Ax+By+Cz+D=0,
$$
then its normal vector $N=(A,B,C)$ is parallel to the plane you need. If the point outside is $P(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and the center of the sphere is $C(a,b,c)$ then the plane I mentioned in my comment has normal vector
$$
N_1=N\times PC
$$
and contains the point $C$ (or $P$). So its equation is
$$
\pi_1: N_1\times (x-a,y-b,z-c)=0.
$$
The points you are looking for solve the system formed by the two planes and the sphere. You get two points, the farthest and the closest.

By the way, the "equation" of the circle is a system of two equations, that of the sphere and that of $\pi$. From those, you can derive parametric equations as well.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I would require the circle equation. The only thing I am not sure about is the deriving parametric equation for the circle.. I will try :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured I would post the nice visualisation followed by the @GReyes answer.

We can see that the planes eq1 and eq3 intersect with the sphere eq 2 at two points and the closer one is the one denoted by P.

Plane eq3 goes through the sphere origin, circle centre and the given point.[image: Visualisation of the answer]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).